# How to add friends of Game Center via URL Schemes?

Tags: ios, game-center, url-scheme

In an App SNS, or App Forum, users would like to show their Game Center ID for making friends. My question is how to add friends via *gamecenter://* URL schemes?

[This topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226195/game-center-url-scheme) had discussed about *gamecenter://* to open a specified game.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that we would be given the power to programmatically add friends for the user.

The linked thread with the detailed regular expressions seem to suggest that the best way to do this would be to go to that player's Game Center profile page and let the user click on the "Send Friend Request" button.  I tried the following scheme, but I can only get to a blank friend profile page, not an actual profile.  I've tried several different things for the 'id'.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"gamecenter://static.gc.apple.com/players/player/<id>/"]];
```

Even if someone did figure it out, because it's undocumented Apple could change at any time in the future so I wouldn't hardcode a URL like this into an app.